# Django rest framework update if item exists

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have the following model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    itemID = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.FloatField()
```

and the following Serializer:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= Item
        fields = ('id','itemID','url','name','price')
```

When posting an item that already exists I get the following message:

```
{"itemID":["item with this itemID already exists."]}
```

Instead, however, I would like to update all other fields if the item already exists.

Comment: There are another HTTP method called put and patch for doing what you want to do.
That is standard in REST architecture.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be best if you could include your `view` in your original post. That being said, model views will usually behave like so:

Assuming we have an `Item` view located at `api/item/`

- To create an item, you `POST` at `api/item/`. It is mapped to the `create` method
- To update an item, you `PATCH` or `PUT` at `api/item/[item_id]/`. It is mapped to the `update` method
- To fetch an item, you `GET` at `api/item/[item_id]/`. It is mapped to the `partial_update` method
- To delete an item, you `DELETE` at `api/item/[item_id]/`. It is mapped to the `destroy` method
- To list all items, you `GET` at `api/item/`. It is mapped to the `list` method

Those methods and urls are automatically available when using the `ModelViewSet` from Django Rest Framework, though you could override them and make them your own.

When using a `ModelSerializer`, you have 2 choices when initializing the serializer:

- serializer(data=data) will end up **creating** a new model instance on save
- serializer(instance, data=data) will allow you to update an existing instance when saving it